# Retrived null in POST JSON RestKit

Tags: ios, json, restkit, restkit-0.20, rkobjectmapping

I have used RestKit and made a mapping with a managed object. I then use the `postObject` method but I have a problem when retrieved the body as it maps to null.

```
 RKObjectManager  *objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:baseURL];

// Serialize to JSON
objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

[RKObjectManager setSharedManager:objectManager];

RKEntityMapping *searchInfoMapping = [RKEntityMapping mappingForEntityForName:NSStringFromClass([Search class]) inManagedObjectStore: objectManager.managedObjectStore];
searchInfoMapping.identificationAttributes = @[ @"faresQueryType" ];

[searchInfoMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id" : @"ID",
    @"type" : @"Type",
    @"count" : @"Count",
    @"route” : @"route”,
}];

RKObjectMapping     *searchInfoRequestMapping =[RKObjectMapping requestMapping];
[searchInfoRequestMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:@{
    @"id" : @"ID",
    @"type" : @"Type",
    @"count" : @"Count",
    @"route” : @"route”,
}];

//Data mapping is a method that returns an RKObjectMapping for my model
RKResponseDescriptor * searchDescriptor = [RKResponseDescriptor responseDescriptorWithMapping:searchInfoMapping pathPattern:nil keyPath:nil statusCodes:RKStatusCodeIndexSetForClass(RKStatusCodeClassSuccessful)];
[objectManager addResponseDescriptorsFromArray:@[searchDescriptor,]];

//Inverse mapping, to perform a POST

RKRequestDescriptor *requestDescriptor = [RKRequestDescriptor requestDescriptorWithMapping:searchInfoRequestMapping  objectClass:[Search class] rootKeyPath:nil];
[objectManager addRequestDescriptor:requestDescriptor];


[appDelegate.objectManager postObject:nil path:@"routes" parameters:postParameters success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
            NSLog(@"Success case %@",mappingResult);
        } failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            NSLog(@"Failure in Flight Mapping %@",error);
            [alert show];
        }];
```

**Edit**

```
      //JSON Result 

    {
    "currency": {
        "code": "USD",
        "name": "U.S. Dollar",
        "symbol": "US$",
        "exchange_rate": 1
    },
    "routes": [
        {
            "id": "MS648-2022:MS985-2110",
            "fares": [
                {
                    "price": 745.32,
                    "description": "Economy",
                    "deeplink": "http://www.wego.com/flights/providers/2/deeplinks?search_id=CQtxCXQCRfmwhp72PAjopQ&trip_id=RUH:NYC:2013-12-20&fare_id=sky-tours.com:0&route=RUH-JFK",
                    "provider_code": "sky-tours.com",
                    "deeplink_params": {
                        "trip_id": "RUH:NYC:2013-12-20",
                        "route": "RUH-JFK",
                        "search_id": "CQtxCXQCRfmwhp72PAjopQ",
                        "fare_id": "sky-tours.com:0"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Give more details of the JSON sent and received.

Comment: The `searchInfoMapping` seems to have no comparison to the result JSON. How is the `Search` object supposed to relate to the returned JSON? I would expect the search object to have a relationship to the `routes` info in the JSON...

Comment: I got you before the root value but now i need to retrieved the "routes" , simply consider "Search" is "routes" .

Comment: `Search` is a single object being posted, so RestKit wants to map the POST back into that single object. Something like overall detail into that object and then the `routes` into a relationship. Can you work like that?

Comment: Do you have a good example in RestKit JSON using POST with CoreData?

Comment: RestKit github page has example code. I'm more interested in modifying your data model and then mapping the data you have into it. To me, and RestKit, it makes sense to have an object recording the search details and linking to the obtained results.

Comment: What is the object attribute should be send to postObject method

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43325/discussion-between-wain-and-wod)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to supply the `Search` object instead of `nil` when you call `postObject` (currently you have `postObject:nil`). This tells RestKit which request mapping to use to send the request. As a result of not setting it the server will likely not have all of the required information (it's impossible to tell with the information provided).

Comment: But i call the postObject method in viewcontroller and mapping in appDelegation

Comment: It doesn't matter where you call it from. Do you have a `Search` instance that you should be passing? What are you expecting to be sent and received? What is `postParameters`?

Comment: Yes i have Search instance in CoreData managed object , and postParameters is NsMutableDictionary.I have tested now without using coreData and mapping it is work fine.But when i use mapping with above code sometimes retrieved data and sometimes the relationship data isn't retrieved

Comment: I think you should add a mapping for `faresQueryType` - and show details of what you send and receive...

Comment: Could you help me by provide me full example RestKit JSON POST data with mapping and response & request descriptor?

Comment: Now i got this error after update may code with Search class <RKMappingOperation 0x8cfbb90> for '__NSDictionaryM' object. Mapping values from object Search ((null)) to object {
} with object mapping (null)

Comment: @Wain would you chat now about this issue ?

Comment: @JAHelia, what do you need to know (and how related to this question)?

Comment: @Wain I'm involved in the same issue with my friend wod, is it ok to chat for couple minutes ?

Comment: Haven't created a room before, this might work: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43373/chitchat

Comment: @Wain are you available for chitchat for couple of minutes ?

Comment: Not at the time of day, sorry. If you have one quick question (though I might not reply for an hour or two...)

Comment: @Wain the problem looks like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632743/restkit-fetching-empty-results-on-subsequent-fetches   the response body contains arrays along with some other stuff (this is clearly depicted in this screenshot: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/jsonArc.png ), the problem lies within all arrays in the JSON response, sometimes these arrays return empty and sometimes return with data, I've subclassed RKObjectManager and set cache policy to NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData in requestWithObject method but to no avail.

Comment: @Wain there is no problem with mappings since data when returned, the response is mapped and persisted to core data entities as expected. why do there arrays return as empty in some subsequent calls. p.s. I've updated RestKit to the latest version 0.20.3 and we have a doubt that it is an NSURLConnection caching issue as commented in the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632743/restkit-fetching-empty-results-on-subsequent-fetches

Comment: Do you mean that the response from the server is empty sometimes? Or the response is the same as the previous response? This is from the server, before RestKit starts processing the data...

Comment: the response contains many arrays and dictionaries (as in the posted screenshot above) all arrays return empty (zero objects in them) sometimes. by the way, this isn't a server issue because my friend connects to this web service on Android and he didn't face such issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be a cache issue, check the values that are being sent to the server. A cache problem would mean the server wasn't called at all.

Comment: the values are OK ( i enabled rest kit logging - trace level) all values in the request header and body are correct.

Comment: here is a WiredShark screenshot for the empty returned array:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/noRoutes.png

and here is a screenshot for the array when it got returned with objects:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/57066689/withRoutes.png

Comment: So that would seem to prove is has nothing to do with RestKit processing the response (because the response is different and empty). Which suggests it is something to do with the request or the server.

Comment: @Wain yes exactly, it is something to do with the request, the web service has no problems when invoked by PostMan plug-in for Chrome, so the request is the suspect. are you available for chat for 5 minutes ?